# BlackBerry - Dialog.cancel() on the login page

Tags: blackberry, dialog, listener

I have a login page that accepts username & password. When the user clicks "Login" a loading screen "Signing in.." is shown with the background thread calling a doLogin() method that calls a web service and load the appropriate page.

The problem I am facing is to "Cancel" signing in from `Dialog.cancel()` after login has been clicked. It cancels the loading screen but the background thread is still processing and even after clicking "cancel", the new page is loaded. How can I cancel the background thread?

```java
Thread backgroundWorker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        doLogin(uname, pwd);
    }
});
Dialog busyDialog = new Dialog("Signing in...",
                               new String [] { "Cancel" },
                               new int [] { Dialog.CANCEL},
                               Dialog.CANCEL,
                               Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.HOURGLASS))
{
    public void fieldChanged(Field field1, int context1)
    {
        //Something to stop the login and close the loading screen
    }
};
busyDialog.setEscapeEnabled(false);
busyDialog.show();
backgroundWorker.start();
```

And the method which it is calling that pushes the new screen is `doLogin()`:

```java
private String doLogin(String user_id, String password)
{
    SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = null;
    HttpConnection httpConn = null;
    HttpTransport httpt;
    SoapPrimitive response = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("username", user_id);
    request.addProperty("password", password);
    System.out.println("The request is=======" + request.toString());
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    httpt = new HttpTransport(URL+C0NNECTION_EXTENSION);
    httpt.debug = true;
    try
    {
        httpt.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        String result = response.toString();
        resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        String[] listResult = split(result, sep);
        strResult = listResult[0].toString();
        if(strResult.equals("credentialdenied"))
        {
            Dialog.alert("Invalid login details.");
        }
        else
        {
            strsessionFirstName = listResult[1].toString();
            strsessionLastName = listResult[2].toString();
            strsessionPictureUrl = MAINURL + listResult[3].substring(2);
            strsessionStatusId = listResult[4].toString();
            strsessionStatusMessage = listResult[5].toString();
            strsessionLastUpdateTst = listResult[6].toString();
        }
        if(strResult.equals("credentialaccepted"))
        {
            if(checkBox1.getChecked() == true)
            {
                persistentHashtable.put("username", user_id);
                persistentHashtable.put("password", password);
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = getLiveImage(strsessionPictureUrl, 140, 140);
            nextScreen.getUsername(user_id);
            nextScreen.getPassword(password);
            nextScreen.setPictureUrl(bitmap);
            nextScreen.setImage(strsessionPictureUrl);
            nextScreen.setFirstName(strsessionFirstName, strsessionLastName, strsessionLastUpdateTst, strsessionStatusMessage);
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable()
            {
                public void run ()
                {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
                }
            } );
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("The exception is IO==" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        System.out.println("The exception xml parser example==="
           + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println( resultRequestSOAP);
    return response + "";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to add a `boolean` member variable to your class, that you check at multiple steps, within your `doLogin()` method:

```java
private boolean stopRequested = false;

private synchronized void requestStop() {
    stopRequested = true;
}

private synchronized boolean isStopRequested() {
    return stopRequested;
}

private String doLogin(String user_id, String password)          
{          
    SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = null;          
    HttpConnection httpConn = null;          
    HttpTransport httpt;          
    SoapPrimitive response = null;          
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);          
    request.addProperty("username", user_id);          
    request.addProperty("password", password);          
    System.out.println("The request is=======" + request.toString());          
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);          
    envelope.dotNet = true;          
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);          
    httpt = new HttpTransport(URL+C0NNECTION_EXTENSION);          
    httpt.debug = true;

    if (isStopRequested()) return null;          

    try          
    {          
        httpt.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);          
        response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();          
        String result = response.toString();          
        resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;          
        String[] listResult = split(result, sep);          
        strResult = listResult[0].toString();          
        if(strResult.equals("credentialdenied"))          
        {          
            Dialog.alert("Invalid login details.");          
        }          
        else          
        {          
            strsessionFirstName = listResult[1].toString();          
            strsessionLastName = listResult[2].toString();          
            strsessionPictureUrl = MAINURL + listResult[3].substring(2);          
            strsessionStatusId = listResult[4].toString();          
            strsessionStatusMessage = listResult[5].toString();          
            strsessionLastUpdateTst = listResult[6].toString();          
        }    

        if (isStopRequested()) return null;          

        if(strResult.equals("credentialaccepted"))          
        {          
            if(checkBox1.getChecked() == true)          
            {          
                persistentHashtable.put("username", user_id);          
                persistentHashtable.put("password", password);          
            }          
            Bitmap bitmap = getLiveImage(strsessionPictureUrl, 140, 140);          
            nextScreen.getUsername(user_id);          
            nextScreen.getPassword(password);          
            nextScreen.setPictureUrl(bitmap);          
            nextScreen.setImage(strsessionPictureUrl);          
            nextScreen.setFirstName(strsessionFirstName, strsessionLastName, strsessionLastUpdateTst, strsessionStatusMessage);

            if (isStopRequested()) return null;          

            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater( new Runnable()          
            {          
                public void run ()          
                {          
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);          
                }          
            } );          
        }          
    } catch (IOException e) {          
        System.out.println("The exception is IO==" + e.getMessage());          
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {          
        System.out.println("The exception xml parser example==="          
           + e.getMessage());          
    }          
    System.out.println( resultRequestSOAP);          
    return response + "";          
}
```

Then, stop the thread like this:

```java
Dialog busyDialog = new Dialog("Signing in...",               
                               new String [] { "Cancel" },               
                               new int [] { Dialog.CANCEL},               
                               Dialog.CANCEL,               
                               Bitmap.getPredefinedBitmap(Bitmap.HOURGLASS))               
{               
    public void fieldChanged(Field field1, int context1)               
    {               
        requestStop();               
    }               
};
```

Comment: @Sarah, you're welcome.  By the way, I did look into an alternate method of killing the thread's running code, using `backgroundWorker.interrupt()`, but after looking more at the documentation, that doesn't look reliable/stable.  So, I think you just need to do something like what I posted above, and put the check `if (isStopRequested()) return null;` in as many places within `doLogin()` as you like.

Comment: yes before posting my question here I had played around the code and tried backgroundWorker.interrupt(). However that did not work for me.

Comment: if I need to stop a thread of a GPSHandler that is called from another class, can it be done through a similar way?I know its another question but since the subject is the same I thought to write here, as to how to cancel a thread called from another class. Is it ok to ask here or should I post that as a new question?

Comment: @Sarah, it looks like you already posted another question, but **yes**, you could use a similar technique. Create a `stopRequested` member variable, and then a `requestStop()` and `isStopRequested()` method (they should be declared `synchronized` like above). The difference in this case would be that if you want to stop the thread from another class, `requestStop()` must be a `public`, not a `private` method in the `GPSHandler` class.

Comment: I tried adding the methods in the GPSHandler class and calling them from another class when "cancel" is clicked. However though the dialog disappears the thread in GPSHandler is still executed in the background. Can you help me on this?